# Creating a table from a comma separated list in LaTeX3

Tags: tables, expl3, latex3, comma-separated-list

I have a comma separated list and want to create a table from it, like so:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{c | c}
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \clist_new:N \test_clist
        \clist_set:Nn \test_clist {a, b, c, d}
        \clist_item:Nn \test_clist {1}  & \clist_item:Nn \test_clist {2} \\ 
        \ExplSyntaxOff
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But I only get an undefined control sequence error. However, without the use of an `&` it works:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{c | c}
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \clist_new:N \test_clist
        \clist_set:Nn \test_clist {a, b, c, d}
        \clist_item:Nn \test_clist {1} \clist_item:Nn \test_clist {2} \\ 
        \ExplSyntaxOff
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Though this is not what I want, as the `a` and `b` are in the same cell of the table.

So how do I make a row of a table from a comma seperated list?

Comment: You cannot switch to expl3 syntax within tabular. You have (at least) two options: Switch expl3 on/off outside of tabular, or map the names to 'normal' LaTeX names.

Comment: Would you please add a “real world” example? This can't work, because you're setting `\test_clist` in the first alignment cell and so the value will be forgotten as soon as `&` is scanned.

Comment: Btw, you don't have to load `expl3`, as it is part of LaTeX since 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Switch expl3 on/off outside of `tabular`. Note that definitions in the first cell of the `tabular` are local to this cell, so the list will be undefined in the second. Means that it is better to move these definitions outside.

```
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \clist_new:N \test_clist
        \clist_set:Nn \test_clist {a, b, c, d}
    \begin{tabular}{c | c}
        \clist_item:Nn \test_clist {1}  & \clist_item:Nn \test_clist {2} \\ 
    \end{tabular}
        \ExplSyntaxOff
```

**Solution 2:** Use expl3 in the preamble to define the commands and make sure that macros that are used later on follow the conventional TeX rules.

```
\documentclass[margin=0.1cm]{standalone}
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \clist_new:N \testclist
        \clist_set:Nn \testclist {a, b, c, d}
        \let\clistitem\clist_item:Nn
        \ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c | c}
        \clistitem\testclist{1}  & \clistitem\testclist{2} \\ 
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution with [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package. You need to use global variable (`\gTestClist`) since every cell in a table makes a group.

```
\documentclass[margin=0.1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{functional}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
 \ClistNew \gTestClist
 \ClistSet \gTestClist {a, b, c, d}
 \ClistVarItem \gTestClist {1} & \ClistVarItem \gTestClist {2} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]